# ssh_dispatch_run_fatal git error after updating my macbook to MacOs Mojave

Tags: git, ssh, terminal

I recently updated to MacOs Mojave on my Macbook but there have been some issues using git via Terminal. The first error was fixed by installing xCode which was easy afterwards I was able to do everything except commands that include the server such as git push / pull when I run git pull which has always been working I get an error message like this

ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to [some ip] port 22: incorrect signature

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

The same happens when trying to git push.

and I cant seem to fix this error any suggestions on how to fix it??

Kind regards Julian

Comment: Somehow following these steps resolved my issue https://serverfault.com/questions/44222/how-do-i-fix-ssh-on-a-mac

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this message means that the remote server is misconfigured or out of date.  Some versions of Gerrit before 2.16 (and possibly other applications using the Apache Mina SSH server) make incorrect signatures when using Ed25519 keys.  (It's also possible, but unlikely, that you have a broken network card or proxy in place.)

The best way to fix this is to update the remote server such that it uses a fixed version of the appropriate SSH code.  For Gerrit, this means upgrading to 2.15 or newer.  Anyone else using an up-to-date OpenSSH will also have this problem and will be unable to access the server.

The alternative is to configure your system not to use Ed25519 for SSH to that system.  If the remote system has the hostname `example.com`, you can add something like the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host example.com
    HostKeyAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Since I am not working on a Windows PC I don't really know what you are reffering to or what to do

Comment: It means that the server you're trying to push your code to has a bug with how it handles the SSH protocol, which is used for pushing and pulling.  You should update it, or modify the configuration file I mentioned, or switch to using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already pointed out:
"Usually, this message means that the remote server is misconfigured or out of date. Some versions of Gerrit before 2.16  make incorrect signatures when using Ed25519 keys."

The solution is to configure your system not to use Ed25519 for SSH to that system. Use HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa

- Open Git Bash in admin mode
- 

```
vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

- 'I' for insert mode
- Add a line: `HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa`
  [image]

now do git clone ssh userid@abc.com:29512/Folder_name

Answer (score 0):

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
root@T301server:/home/git/Hello-World.git# git commit -m 'config'
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
HEAD
config
description
hooks/
info/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
root@T301server:/home/git/Hello-World.git# git push pi master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@192.168.142.139:/home/git/Hello-World.git'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).